# Change Appbar backgroundColor in MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The default Appbar color is set by MUI to the primary color, which is the blue color.
If I wanted to change that color directly using `sx={{ background: 'white' }}`, then I will lose the feature of the dark theme. In other words, the background color white will stuck even when the MUI dark mode theme is applied. Which is an unwanted behavior.

So, How I can change the background color of the Appbar in the correct way while keeping the support for the dark mode feature of Mui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, you simply have to use the prop `color` instead of using the prop `sx` to change the background color of the `Appbar` component,

for example:

```js
<Appbar color="default">  here
   <Toolbar disableGutters sx={{ pl: 3 }}>
      ... etc
```

Setting the `color` prop to `"default"` is going to change the color to white, and when you switch to dark theme, it's going to apply the dark theme automatically for it.

You can use other variants of the color prop as well, ex: `primary`, `success`, `secondary`.

Answer (score 3):

First check the user's preference between a light or dark theme:

```
import useMediaQuery from '@mui/material/useMediaQuery';
const prefersDarkMode = useMediaQuery('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)')
```

Then you can set the `AppBar`'s color accordingly:

```
const appBarColor = prefersDarkMode ? darkColor : lightColor
return <AppBar sx = {{ background: appBarColor }} />
```

You may also choose to check the value of `theme.palette.mode` to determine the color in that manner.

[useMediaQuery](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-use-media-query/)

[prefers-color-scheme](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme)

Comment: How well is this CSS query selector '(prefers-color-scheme: dark)' supported by older browsers? (excluding internet explorer of course)

Comment: Thanks @pez, I found the second solution better, easier, and more supported, which is to check the value of `theme.palette.mode`